# Convert a string to a date in the format of `dd MMM yyy`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have users inputting their DOB using a `UIDatePicker`, which gets put into a `UITextField` (as a String) with the format `dd MMM yyyy`. For example, a DOB of 12th September 1999 would appear as 12 Sep 1999.

How do I use DateFormatter() to convert this and for storage in a CoreData entity with an attribute type of Date?

Using

```
let dob = "12 Sep 1999"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")

dateFormatter.date(from: dob)
```

Returns `Sep 12, 1999 at 12:00 AM`, which would be fine but I don't know how to get rid of "at 12:00 AM"?

Comment: You can get `Date` object directly from `UIDatePicker.date`. Is that an option?

Comment: Done @Cristik, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What are you after here? The `Date` class holds a timestamp, a date with a time. You can't avoid having a time as part of a `Date`. Your code can ignore the time if you only want to deal with the day.

Comment: Once saved, the users can then view the saved records. Previously I stored the DOB just as an unformatted String, and then to display it I used `dob2.text = patientResult?.value(forKeyPath: "dob") as? String`, but I'm not sure how to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` instance is a point in time (actually a `Double` value). It doesn't know time zones, locales and any date formats.

Think the other way round:

- In your `NSManagedObject` subclass declare the property as `Date`

  ```
  @NSManaged public var dob: Date
  ```
- Get the `date` from the date picker and save that.
- Add a computed property in the `NSManagedObject` subclass to be able to display only the date portion as string

  ```
  var dobString : String {
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
      dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
      dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
      return dateFormatter.string(from: dob)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what is returned from `dateFormatter.date` is a `Date` object. You can save it to a variable and store it using `CoreDate` as a `Date` object.
What you are seeing is just a string describing the object – so you don’t need to get rid of the "at 12:00".

Comment: Solved using this and @Carpsen90's answer, thank you!
I'll edit my original post with the code used.

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeing is just the `description` property of the date

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dob)!  //"Sep 12, 1999 at 12:00 AM"
dateFormatter.string(from: date)           //"12 Sep 1999"
```